# iOS Says "Connection failed and unsupported" when connecting to Mac through Bluetooth

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, bluetooth, iphone

I'm trying to connect my iPhone 5s to my Early 2011 Mac Book Pro through bluetooth. When I try to connect after pairing, it gives me the following error:

[image: Screenshot of the settings app]

After searching around on the web, I found people saying that this has never been supported, but that's obviously not true! I've done it before, and popular apps like [Knock To Unlock](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/knock-to-unlock/id692929970?mt=8) ***require*** connecting to Mac via bluetooth.

My iPhone is on iOS 7.0.4 and my Mac Book Pro is on 10.9.1.

Can *someone* **please** tell me how to connect?